# How to derive time complexity of the Recurrence Relation - T(n,m) = T(n-1,m) + T(n,m-1) + c

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

I know that, *T(n,m) = T(n-1,m) + T(n,m-1) + c* it's the recurrence equation of Longest Common Subsequence algorithm. And the time complexity of the LCS in case of recursive method is O(2^n+m).

The base condition is: *when m or n = 0, T(m,n) = 1 i.e., T(0,n)=1 and T(m,0)=1*.

But, how do I derive the time complexity from the above recurrence relation?

Comment: When I saw this post, I thought it is quite similar to Pascal's triangle. If you rotate it 60 degree, I guess the relation is almost same(without c). Then, what's the complexity of nCr?

Comment: The Wikipedia entry gives a slightly different recurrence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#LCS_function_defined

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/159629/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Let $S(m,n)=T(m,n)+c$. Then it satisfies the recurrence relation $S(m,n)=S(m-1,n)+S(m,n-1)$ with the initial conditions $S(m,0)=S(0,n)=1+c$ for all nonnegative $m$ and $n$. Therefore, $S(m,n)=(1+c)\binom{m+n}{n}$, so $T(m,n)=(1+c)\binom{m+n}{n}-c$.